# outputting to a file in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a program that is a game tournament that battles recursively and deletes players from a player container until there is only 1 player left. It is the card game War, and for every battle I need to output the winner of each battle in the game to a file. So for example it would look something like this

```
John vs James
    Battle 1: James wins
    Battle 2: John wins
    ...
    Battle 5: James wins, John is out of cards. James wins the game
```

but then since this is a tournament, John gets removed from the container and the next two people battle so we go from 16 to 8 to 4 to 2 players and then lastly the winner. I already have the code for this all worked out I need need to know how I can do this part recursively:

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(argv[2]);

outFile << player1Name << " vs. " << player2Name << endl;

outFile << "Battle" << //number battle & winner etc, etc
```

I want to do this so that every time the PROGRAM is ran, it overrides everything in the file, but everytime a GAME is played within the tournament it just adds to the end of the previous battle. I have a few ideas but I'm not sure what's the best way to go about this. I was thinking about putting

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(argv[2]);
```

In the driver.cpp file, then calling the recursive function game.tournament() but passing in game.tournament(outFile), into void Game::tournament(ofstream& outFile) then using the outFile << statements and calling doing the recursive call tournament(outFile) and once the recursive function ends, .close() the file back in the driver.cpp. Would this work the way I think it would? As in it opens and closes in the driver, but I have access to print out to it in the recursive function

Also to be clear the base case is when the queue of players has a .size() < 2, meaning it has only 1 player left in it and thus that player is the winner, that's why my recursive function has a void return value. This is not the part I need help with but I figured I'd include it in case people were wondering

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your program, before calling the recursion open your file like this

```
outFile.open(argv[2], std::ofstream::trunc);
```

This will truncate everything from the file, then close it.

Next in your recursive function, open the file for appending like this

```
outFile.open(filename, std::ofstream::app);
```

See the [reference for ofstream here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/)